# Run C++ exe from web

Tags: php, c++, web-services, web, exe

I have developed an C++ application which reads from 2 input files.
The app analyzes the files, and in response creates a new file with new information.
All of the above works on my machine, but recently the project's managers added a request to make a Web GUI.

The users should be able to load the 2 files from their local machine to the folder and than the server will run the EXE file that will put a new output file in the folder.
When the EXE is done running, the output file will be represented to the user in the client side.

I am in charge of the application, so we hired a company to make the web side.

The EXE file is located on the server with the web site files.
The company wrote it in PHP, and when a user wants to get the output file, they run the EXE file with the function "exec".
In response they get an error that this function isn't available because of security issues.
From what I understand, all that needs to be done, is to enable the function from php.ini,
but the company told me that the problem is with my application.

I'm writing this question, because I'm not sure how this should be done, and I wanted to know what is the right way to go, in order to answer the project requirements.

Maybe a web service, written in C++ that will replace my EXE file?(tell me if i'm completely wrong :))

Thanks a lot, Ben.

Comment: Is the web site hosted on a Windows server, or Linux?

Comment: If you are able to run the application from a shell on that server machine, then there's no problem with your "EXE" application at all. Essentially, if you are able to execute it, PHP should be able to as well..

Comment: You are right, it needs to be enabled in `php.ini` See [disable_functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) directive

Comment: also, check [safe_mode](http://www.php.net/features.safe-mode), can be case for old php

Comment: One option, if you can't get exec to work, is to use a periodic task (cron or windows equivalent) that simply checks every x minutes if there is input in some input directory and if so processes it and writes it to an output directory. Then the PHP script just needs to move the uploaded files to the input directory and check periodically till the output is ready.